# Build libraries in different build folders in GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to setup a build system that supports building libraries and executables in separate folders without having to resort to a recursive make. 
My current directory tree is as follows:

```
Project
├── Foo
│   └── src
│       └── foo.c
├── Bar
|   └── Source
|       └── bar.c
├── App 
|   └── src
|       └── main.c
└── Makefile
```

Notice the "Source" instead of "src" in the Bar folder.

I would like to be able to generate the following build directory:

```
Build
├── Foo
│   ├── foo.o
│   └── foo.a
├── Bar
│   ├── bar.o
│   └── bar.a
└── App 
    ├── main.o
    └── app.exe
```

I have not yet found a way to generate a wildcard recipe to generate the objects/libs/bins in the right build directory without repeating myself:

```
BUILD_DIR := Path/To/Build
CC ?= gcc

.PHONY: all
all: Foo Bar

# Foo
FOO_DIR = Foo
FOO_SRCS = foo.c
FOO_OBJS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)/,$(FOO_SRCS:.c=.o))

.PHONY: Foo
Foo: $(FOO_OBJS)

## This line has to be repeated for Bar as well
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)/%.o: $(FOO_DIR)/src/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

# Bar
BAR_DIR = Bar
BAR_SRCS = bar.c
BAR_OBJS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)/,$(BAR_SRCS:.c=.o))

.PHONY: Bar
Bar: $(BAR_OBJS)

## Here, I am repeating the same line as in Foo
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)/%.o: $(BAR_DIR)/Source/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

# Utils
$(BUILD_DIR)/%:
    mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: Any specific reason why not to use recursive make? It will allow you to isolate different build configurations in separate `make` instances, i.e. less danger of pollution, incorrect build artifacts and strange build problems.

Comment: That said, you may want to study [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54614765/8866606) how to dynamically generate dependencies between sources and object files from variables and using static pattern rules to avoid code repetition.

Comment: Please have a look at [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015453/building-c-program-out-of-source-tree-with-gnu-make/39033569#39033569)

Comment: @StefanBecker I cannot use a recursive make, since the "Bar" library is out of the source tree (I omitted this in the question). This is also why its source uses a different directory name.

Comment: @Rogozhin one solution for that would be to add a makefile for "Bar" in your current tree that includes a Makefile (fragment) from "Bar" source tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a static pattern rule to avoid code repetition and dynamically generated dependencies. Something like this should do it:

```makefile
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

FOO_DIR  := Foo
FOO_SRCS := a

BAR_DIR  := Bar
BAR_SRCS := b

# Macros to dynamically generate dependencies
OBJS :=
DIRS :=
# $(1): directory path
# $(2): source directory path relative to $(1)
#       (will also be the relative path in build directory)
# $(3): source/object file base name
# NOTE: the empty line at the end of the macro is on purpose!
define obj_dependencies
_dir := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(1)
_obj := $$(_dir)/$(3).o
$$(_obj): $(1)/$(2)/$(3).c | $$(_dir)
DIRS += $$(_dir)
OBJS += $$(_obj)
_dir :=
_obj :=

endef

# $(1): directory path
# $(2): source directory path relative to $(1)
# $(3): list of file base names
objs_for_dir = $(eval $(foreach _o,$(3),$(call obj_dependencies,$(strip $(1)),$(strip $(2)),$(_o))))

# Generate dependencies for given directories & sources
$(call objs_for_dir,$(FOO_DIR),src,$(FOO_SRCS))
$(call objs_for_dir,$(BAR_DIR),Source,$(BAR_SRCS))

# build all object files
all: $(OBJS)

# Sources -> objects
$(OBJS): %.o:
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

# Utils
$(DIRS): | $(BUILD_DIR)
$(BUILD_DIR) $(DIRS):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Mind you, I typed this straight from my head, so there might be typos. But at least it should give you an idea how to achieve what you want.

---

This could be optimized to only call `$(eval)` once, e.g.

```makefile
objs_for_dir = $(foreach _o,$(3),$(call obj_dependencies,$(strip $(1)),$(strip $(2)),$(_o)))

# Generate dependencies for given directories & sources
$(eval \
    $(call objs_for_dir,$(FOO_DIR),src,$(FOO_SRCS))    \
    $(call objs_for_dir,$(BAR_DIR),Source,$(BAR_SRCS)) \
)
```

Comment: The macro function does not seem to produce the dependencies. Afaik "_dir" and "_obj" are empty when the macro is evaluated.

Comment: Done and verified. Writing macros that are `$(eval)`'d can lead to dollaritis :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do this. Let's take it in stages. We start with these rules:

```
.PHONY: all
    all: Foo Bar

.PHONY: Foo
Foo: $(FOO_OBJS)

.PHONY: Bar
Bar: $(BAR_OBJS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)/%.o: $(FOO_DIR)/src/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)/%.o: $(BAR_DIR)/Source/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

(Note that your diagram says `Foo/source` and `Bar/Src`, but your makefile says `Foo/src` and `Bar/Source`. Adjust as needed.)
We eliminate the intermediate targets and turn the object rules into [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
.PHONY: all
    all:  $(FOO_OBJS) $(BAR_OBJS)

$(FOO_OBJS): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)/%.o: $(FOO_DIR)/src/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(BAR_OBJS): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)/%.o: $(BAR_DIR)/Source/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

Then we separate the static pattern rules into their specific an generic parts:

```
$(FOO_OBJS): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)/%.o: $(FOO_DIR)/src/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)

$(FOO_OBJS):
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(BAR_OBJS): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)/%.o: $(BAR_DIR)/Source/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)

$(BAR_OBJS):
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

**And finally combine the generic parts:**

```
$(FOO_OBJS): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)/%.o: $(FOO_DIR)/src/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)/$(FOO_DIR)

$(BAR_OBJS): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)/%.o: $(BAR_DIR)/Source/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)/$(BAR_DIR)

$(FOO_OBJS) $(BAR_OBJS):
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```